# Batch File FOR Loop 7-zip extract specific file extension

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file, 7-zip, file-extension

I am trying to create a batch file to recursively extract multiple archives in multiple sub-directories from a source directory to an output directory while keeping archive folder structure. The below example works perfectly EXCEPT that I need to extract only one specific file type from each archive (i.e., .txt., .doc, .pdf, etc.) What do I need to change in order to make this work?

```
@ECHO ON

SET source=C:\Users\user\Desktop\test
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /S /B "%source%\*.zip"') DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%~fF" -o"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Working\Custom Textures\*"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /S /B "%source%\*.7z"') DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%~fF" -o"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Working\Custom Textures\*"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /S /B "%source%\*.rar"') DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%~fF" -o"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Working\Custom Textures\*"
PAUSE
```

I sincerely appreciate the help in advance, and any thorough resources on batch scripting that I could be directed to for future references would be greatly appreciated as well, as I am trying to learn.

Comment: @Worthwelle: This says [tag:windows] [tag:batch-file], not [tag:linux] [tag:shell-script]. `#` is *not* a valid comment character. Instead either use the `REM` command, or start the line with `::` (or you could just delete the offending lines).

Comment: Yup, I managed to confuse myself. Let's try this again: If you only need to extract `*.7z` files, then you can comment out (using `::` or `REM`) or remove the first and third `FOR` loops (lines 4 and 6).

Comment: My apologies. I should have worded myself better. I do want each archive extension as above, but what I need is from each archive to only extract one file type, i.e. .txt, .doc, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-i` switch with 7-Zip for this. As an example, the following modification of your batch file will only extract `.txt` files.

```
@ECHO ON

SET source=C:\Users\user\Desktop\test
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /S /B "%source%\*.zip"') DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%~fF" -o"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Working\Custom Textures\*" -ir!*.txt
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /S /B "%source%\*.7z"') DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%~fF" -o"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Working\Custom Textures\*" -ir!*.txt
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /S /B "%source%\*.rar"') DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%~fF" -o"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Working\Custom Textures\*" -ir!*.txt
PAUSE
```

Here is some more information from [the documentation](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/include.htm):

> ## -i (Include filenames) switch
>
> Specifies additional include filenames and wildcards.
>
> Multiple include switches are supported.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> -i[<recurse_type>]<file_ref>
>
> <recurse_type> ::= r[- | 0]
> <file_ref> ::= @{listfile} | !{wildcard}
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `<recurse_type>`
>
> Specifies how wildcards and file names in this switch must be used. If this option is not given, then the global value, assigned by
>   the -r (Recurse) switch will be used. For more details see
>   specification of the -r (Recurse) switch.
>
> ```
> <recurse_type> ::= r[- | 0]
> ```
>
> `<file_ref>`
>
> Specifies filenames and wildcards, or a list file, for files to be processed.
>
> ```
> <file_ref> ::= @{listfile} | !{wildcard}
>
> Option        Description
> {listfile}    Specifies name of list file. See List file description.
> {wildcard}    Specifies wildcard or filename.
> ```
>
> Examples
>
> ```
> 7z a -tzip src.zip *.txt -ir!DIR1\*.cpp
> ```
>
> adds to src.zip archive all *.txt files from current directory and all
>   *.cpp files from directory DIR1 and from all it's subdirectories.